# What is the correct way to modify Product Page

Tags: magento-2.1, product, layout, custom

I have a 3rd Party theme (Ves-Fasony) installed and I need to remove the following in Product Page:

- Breadcrumps
- Review
- Add to Wish List
- Add to Compare
- Email

[image]

I removed the 「Add to Wish List」and「Review」by disabling it in Admin Panel.But I am not sure about others, I tried to remove the breadcrumps by doing the following:

1. I created a `layout` folder under the following directory

   [magento_dir]/app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_name]/
2. Then under `layout` folder, I created `default.xml` which has the following code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!--
   /**
    * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
   -->

       <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="page.top" remove="true" />
   </body>
   ```

I am certainly wrong because it is not working. I am a newbie and I am really having a hard time understanding Magento. Please tell me where I went wrong and what should I do to remove those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are an "absolutely correct way" on removing the elements on pages. Even using CSS `display:none` to hide the elements is also a good way.

OK let's back to XML way, just make sure:

1. On correct path. In your case, `[magento_dir]/app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_name]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`
2. Refer to correct block. In your case:

Remove Breadcrumbs

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

Remove Review

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
```

Remove Add to Wish List+Add to Compare+Email

Actually they're in the same container so we can remove it within a line:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.social" remove="true" />
```

Tested on Magento 2.1.7 EE. If you find the block/container cannot remove, most likely you have other modules/themes to override your codes. If that happens, you've to modify the block name accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! It worked and you explained it well. Before I was trying to remove the Email and Add to Compare by the following code '<referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />' but it didn't work. Yours work well. I wonder if you can also teach me how to remove the compare button in the product list. I tried to remove it inside the <custom_module_dir>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/listing.phtml but it didn't work too.

Comment: On `[magento_dir]/app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_name]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`, add `<referenceBlock name="compare" remove="true" />`